how to make pycharm fix whitespace automatically when coding?
I'm using Pycharm to writing a class like this:

when I completed writing super().__init__(),I typed "enter" twice and then I jumped to 50th line and leave a warning like this:

Is there any way to make Pycharm fix the whitespace automatically in real time so that I needn't to reformat code or delete it myself?

It's super hard to understand what is happening here. I have been using Pycharm for several years and not encountered this kind of issue. Can you get screenshots?

did you copy this code from website?

1.I think I've said it clearly, It's about Pycharm's warning
2.Yes, this is the code from github, I'm trying to rewrite it

I know some ways that can fix certain whitespace issues:

Go to File-> settings-> editor -> Code Style -> [choose the language] -> other
,check "add line feed at the end of file" (see picture 1).
This ensures proper whitespace at the end of files. Moreover, you can customize the whitespace preferences for your language here; For example spaces around operators, blank lines between code blocks
picture 1

go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Action on Save
. Enable "Reformat code" (see picture 2).
This will run the formatter on the file every time you save and fix whitespace and other style issues based on your code style settings automatically.
picture 2



I hope these ways are useful for you.


Note that, I am using pycharm 2022.2 (Professional Edition)

Go to Settings/Editor/General, scroll to the bottom and adjust the On Save options. By default PyCharm (and all JetBrain IDEs) automatically saves files, so this will occur whenever you modify a file.

